# Navagation through multiple solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I've created an intranet site for our company.    The address is: http://servername/site

The name of the solution is the same as the server name.  Within the solution is one project with the same name as the site.

What I would like to do is create a home page at the root of the solution and the server that will basically allow users to navigate to added sections.  IE: http://servername/homepage will allow navigation to //servername/site1 and //servername/site2, both of which are separate projects within the solution.

My first question is would my homepage have to be a separate project?
My second question is how would I configure routing between projects?  I know how to setup routes that are all within one project but not quite sure how to create routes that would point to different controllers/views within different projects

Comment: I see questions like this asked on SO several times a week. Every time I see one, it makes me cringe. Why would anyone in their right mind intentionally try to split their web site between multiple projects? This road is clearly fraught with problems from building the application, to working out issues with routing and authorization, to deploying it, to configuring the server to host it on.

Comment: My thinking is that each project will be a different section with different functionality.  Such as a document center, helpdesk, etc.  From an organizational stand point it seems to make sense.  Admittedly I could be way off.  Also I think if I had to edit one section of the site it would make sense that only one project would be affected rather than the entire site that is in one project.

Comment: In MVC, you can use [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to accomplish a "reorganization" within the same project without all of the headaches of working out how to deploy and configure multiple projects.

Comment: Perfect!  I knew there had to be an answer but I didn't know exactly what to search for.  Thanks!